# jQuery to retrieve and set selected option value of html select element

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to retrieve and set the selected value of a select element (drop down list) with jQuery.

for retrievel i have tried `$("#myId").find(':selected').val()`, as well as `$("#myId").val()` but both return undefined.

Any insight into this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: if your using asp .net, they Id may not be the same once rendered!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The way you have it is correct at the moment. Either the id of the select is not what you say or you have some issues in the dom.

Check the Id of the element and also check your markup validates at [here](http://validator.w3.org/) at W3c.

Without a valid dom jQuery cannot work correctly with the selectors.

If the id's are correct and your dom validates then the following applies:

To Read Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val();
```

To Set Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val('newValue');
```

To Read Selected Text

```
$('#selectId>option:selected').text();
```

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("CoinTypes", (SelectList)ViewBag.RequiredLevel, new { @class = "form-control",@style="height: 21px;margin-top: 5px;"})

but $('#CoinTypes').val(@ViewBag.CoinType); is not selecting

Comment: @NithinPaul not a comment really, ask a question that shows html so someone can actually try and work out what is wrong. Not sure how you can expect anyone to work it out from some webforms/mvc code!

Answer (score 251):

to get/set the actual selectedIndex property of the select element use:

```
$("#select-id").prop("selectedIndex");

$("#select-id").prop("selectedIndex",1);
```

Comment: It's important to note that the prop() feature was implemented in version 1.6 so prior versions do not have this functionality.

Comment: I like this answer because it actually answers the question of accessing the index, not just the value.

Comment: yea.  I thought that was the original question.

Comment: You could probably also use attr with the same syntax and be okay.

Comment: @M.YitzhakSamuel `.attr()` and `.prop()` are not synonymous.  It will work in certain instances where an attribute is also a property, e.g. `.attr('id')` is equal to `.prop('id')`.  In this instance, `.prop('selectedIndex')` is equal to `.get(0).selectedIndex`.

Comment: For some reason, this does not trigger the `change` event though?

Answer (score 8):

`$('#myId').val()` should do it, failing that I would try:

```
$('#myId option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 4):

`$("#myId").val()` should work if `myid` is the select element id!

This would set the selected item: `$("#myId").val('VALUE');`

Answer (score 4):

When setting with `JQM`, don't forget to update the `UI`:

```
$('#selectId').val('newValue').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this nugget - was wondering why the new value doesn't show up on screen after changing the selectedIndex with $("#slot-choice").prop("selectedIndex", n).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have created a Drop Down list using SELECT tag like as follows,

```
<select id="Country">
```

Now if you want to see what is the selected value from drop down using JQuery then, simply put following line to retrieve that value..

```
var result= $("#Country option:selected").text();
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just had a bear of a time with Razor, could not get it to work no matter how hard I tried. Kept coming back as "undefined" no matter if I used "text" or "html" for attribute. Finally I added "data-value" attribute to the option and it read that just fine.

```
 <option value="1" data-value="MyText">MyText</option>

 var DisplayText = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-value");
```

Answer (score 0):

$( "#myId option:selected" ).text(); will give you the text that you selected in the drop down element. either way you can change it to .val(); to get the value of it . check the below coding

```
<select id="myId">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>`
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#your_select_element_id').val('your_value').attr().add('selected');
```