# setting value of <select> tag with jQuery

Tags: html

I have a drop down list's select tag that looks like this:

```
<select name="MyName" id="MyID">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

When the user enters the control and selects an option, that option becomes the one that remains visible in the drop-down text when the drop-down box loses its focus. How can I make an option the value that's displayed when the page loads? For the moment, when the page is displayed, the text shows the first option but what if I'd like to show option 4 on load?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery to retrieve and set selected index value of html select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221957/jquery-to-retrieve-and-set-selected-index-value-of-html-select-element) (which came up with a google search using the following string: "jquery selected index")

Comment: @Itay -- it is not a duplicate if the OP is actually asking about HTML and not jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute selected.  To select the third option:

```
<select name="MyName" id="MyID">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option selected="true">Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

To use Jquery to find the selected item:

```
$('#MyId option[@selected]').html
```

Comment: Isn't the `="true"` not needed?

Comment: you can use <option selected="selected">Option 3</option>

Comment: @Hogan, its not required.  But, I like to use XHTML.

Comment: OH!  Then you want `selected="selected"`

Comment: Can I write something like $('#MyID').find('option').eq(3).selected="selected"; ? I'm looking to code the "selected = selected" part

Comment: try: $('#MyId option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', selected);

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML issue.  Just have the html look like this:

```
<select name="MyName" id="MyID">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option selected>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a way to store the selected value, if your using just javascript then you can store the value into a cookie.. but if you have access to server side coding i recommend using php and using session variables to store the value the user selected. once you can acces this stored value you can on page load either use the "selected" attribute or use jquery to change the select to the correct selection

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="MyName" id="MyID">
  <option value="item1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="item2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="item3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="item4" selected>Option 4</option>
</select>
```