# passing a variable to .html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
     <!-- The select drop down menu (works fine) -->
     <select id="select-event-type">
        <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
     </select>

     <!-- The javascript, which is supposed to output something according to the chosen option in the select drop down -->
     <script>
          (function ($) {
              var events = <?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? json_encode($this->events) : "null"; ?>;
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
                      if (events) {
                          var event = events[this.selectedIndex];
                          $('#event-details').html(event);
                      }
                  });
              });
          })($);
     </script>

 <!-- In this div the output will be displayed -->
<div id="event-details"></div>
```

The event variable undefined.
If I for example do this:  `var event = 'hello'` It does output 'hello' as it is supposed to.
So the problem seems to be with this part: `events[this.selectedIndex];`. What did I do wrong?
I am really new to this. Thank you so much for your help!!
**UPDATE**:
Console output (in chrome):

```
     <script>
          (function ($) {
              var events = JSON.parse({"1":{"event_id":"1","event_title":"event1","event_desc":"event1","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event1","event_date":"2022-07-20 15:00:00"},"2":{"event_id":"2","event_title":"event2","event_desc":"event2","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event2","event_date":"2015-04-20 15:00:00"},"3":{"event_id":"3","event_title":"event3","event_desc":"event3","event_location":"eventlocation","event_requirements":"event3","event_date":"2019-11-20 16:00:00"}});               $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
             if (events) {
                 var event = events[$(this).selectedIndex];
                 $('#event-details').html(event);
              }
           });
        });

    </script>
```

**JSON**:

```
{
    "1": {
        "event_id": "1",
        "event_title": "event1",
        "event_desc": "event1",
        "event_location": "eventlocation",
        "event_requirements": "event1",
        "event_date": "2022-07-20 15:00:00"
    },
    "2": {
        "event_id": "2",
        "event_title": "event2",
        "event_desc": "event2",
        "event_location": "eventlocation",
        "event_requirements": "event2",
        "event_date": "2015-04-20 15:00:00"
    },
    "3": {
        "event_id": "3",
        "event_title": "event3",
        "event_desc": "event3",
        "event_location": "eventlocation",
        "event_requirements": "event3",
        "event_date": "2019-11-20 16:00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe use $(this).val() instead of this.selectedIndex

Comment: Could you give the client-side version of this code snippet? .... As rendered in your browser (HTML).

Comment: Events is not a boolean

if (events.length > 0 && events!='null')

Comment: But it runs the script. The `if (events)` runs because it does output the value I give to `var event`.

Comment: Are you certain that the `events` array has values in it? Could you do `console.log(events);` to check on that?

Comment: It says `events is not defined`. But how can that be if there is the JSON in the console? `var event = JSON.parse({"1":{event...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the `select` element use `this.value`. Thus change:

```
var event = events[this.selectedIndex];
```

To:

```
var event = events[this.value];
```

However, if you **json** is an array with indices `0,1,2,3,4` rather than an object with option values as `keys` then your use of `this.selectedIndex` is correct.

**UPDATE**:

In the light of the sample JSON posted the correct code should be:

```
var event = events[this.selectedIndex + 1].event_title;
```

**Special Note**

You can get all the event data by using either:

```
var event = JSON.stringify( events[this.selectedIndex + 1] ); //gives you a string of everything
```

Or you could construct how you want it to look like so:

```
var event = $('<div/>');
$.each( events[this.selectedIndex + 1], function(k,v) {
    event.append( $('<div/>',{text:k + ': ' + v}) );
});
```

Comment: This does not give me any errors but there is no output either.

Comment: `this.value` is consistent across browsers; it's very basic js.

Comment: okay! Well then the problem has to be somewhere else in my code since I do not get any errors I believe you! :)

Comment: Can you post a snippet off the json you're using.

Comment: Amazing!! That works!! How do I manage to get all the other values as well (event_desc, event_requirements etc.)?

Comment: See new update which should give you a clue on how to access the rest of the information.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373474/3667225) for the `jQuery` way of accessing the `selectedIndex` property. Your answer might look like:

```
var event = events[$(this).prop("selectedIndex")];
```

Comment: Thank you that is already helping! Now I get that this is not defined: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you dont need the 2 ready instances. Try to do it, if dont work please tell me.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var events = <?php echo (count($this->events) > 0) ? json_encode($this->events) : "null"; ?>;
      $('#select-event-type').change(function() {
         if (events) {
             var event = events[$(this).selectedIndex];
             $('#event-details').html(event);
          }
       });
    });

</script>
```

and what means the selectedIndex ?

Comment: I do not get any errors but no output either. I am getting the feeling the error is to be searched elsewhere! Thank you for the effort!

Comment: You can try to get the value like this $(this).val() or you can add an attribute data in your element #select-event-type. Example: <input id="select-event-type" data-index="yourvalue">. So you can access $(this).attr("data-index"). hugs!